# Make UITableView go to top line

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I sometimes reload table data and I need to redraw the table so that I see the data from the first row again. What I do now is the following:

```
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop ];
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:ip animated:NO];
```

This is not ideal because there is an annoying flash when row 0 is selected and immediately deselected.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `UITableView`'s [`scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method.

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: that's a great solution, but when you have a large number of records in your table view, it's better to set the animated to NO, sometimes the index gets lost..so the best solution would be :[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

Answer (score 2):

If you have a header that is in view by default, and want to compensate if the action is called when the list is in motion use:

```
[tableview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) animated:NO];
```

Short, simple, effective.

Answer (score 1):

You can set contentoffset of tableview to (0.,0.).